# How to make Git as safe as possible for beginners?

Tags: git

I'm currently working on a course module for programming scientists, on Git and version control. One of the benefits I'm trying to convey (amongst others), is that using VC can safeguard you against loss of work. But of course, as is well-known, Git gives you ample opportunity to shoot yourself in the foot. It'd be a shame to have students in the course loose work because of using a system that was supposed to prevent that from happening in the first place :-)

My question: would you have tips for **things you could teach people (commands, workflows, tricks) that steer them out of trouble when using Git**?

Specifically, this applies mostly to **people with a solo workflow, without prior Git experience**, and possibly beginner-level programmers.

Examples of the kind of tips I'm aware of:

- Push your code to something like GitHub or BitBucket regularly. Also, please make backups, too :)
- Stay away from commands like `git rebase`, until you know what you're doing.
- Make a backup of your code directory (including `.git` dir) before playing with history rewriting, *especially* when you're still learning.

Thanks!

Comment: rebase rocks. always pull --rebase when you can, to stay away from ugly merge commits.

Comment: The only tip I would give to a git beginner would be : do not push your commits until you are satisfied with it.

Comment: If your primary concern is preventing data loss, then a good discussion to have is how often to commit. In my experience, the biggest problems happen when you don't commit your changes in a while and overwrite your working tree. Decide ahead of time when to commit and stick to that rule.

Comment: " But of course, as is well-known, Git gives you ample opportunity to shoot yourself in the foot." -- what opportunities specific to git are you referring to?

Comment: Although I understand one might want to close this question, I'd argue that the quality of the answers shows that this is a useful resource. There are *objectively better* ways to use Git safely, and the answerers are sharing some important ones: make sure your stuff is always committed, check command output (and know what Git's messages mean), and tag commits for later recovery. If there's a way to improve the question, I'd love to hear.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're doing things more complicated than needed.

To be able to recover previous state, regular commits to a local repo is all that is required. You don't have to introduce branching or merging at this stage. Maybe tagging as a way to get back to specific versions.

To reduce the risk of loss of code due to a lost computer / crashed hard drive proper backups is a good advice. But that is the same for everything, not just code.

If you want to introduce code sharing, pushing to github or bitbucket is an option. As long as you only push and you're the only one pushing it is very simple.

Comment: Great point. We'll actually be spending most of our time on the basic solo workflow, as you're suggesting. Still, I have a feeling there might be things we could do to prevent mistakes that can clobber up your repo. Hence the question :) Thanks for chiming in!

Answer (score 1):

The most general rule would be: ensure you know what a command does before using it.

It could be declined in more specific tips:

- More generally that avoiding `git rebase`, we could say avoiding to change the history.
- Avoid using the flag `-f` on a comment (`push`, `clean`, ...)

Having a safety net before doing something potentially dangerous is indeed always a good idea. However, no need to copy the whole directory : just putting a tag on your original commit to be able to `checkout` it if things goes wrong is enough and less cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

As @nullability says, the question of when and how often to commit is really important. If you're only going to commit a monolithic change set every other week, you are effectively losing data because

1. you can not go back to specific intermediate steps you took to arrive at the current change set/solution.
2. every commit is a chance to explain to your future self *in a few words* why you decided to make a specific set of changes. (And in my experience you are much more likely to take the time to write a *meaningful* commit message if the change set is self-contained and does not require you to write multiple paragraphs of text to explain everything.)

Getting people to view `git` (or any decent DVCS, really) as a tool that can actually help *drive* the coding process - instead of a necessary evil - is key here. (To drive that point home you might want to consider showing your students [`git bisect`](http://randyfay.com/content/debugging-git-bisect).)

---

A couple of things to check when determining whether or not a given change set is ready to be committed:

- Can you summarize the changes in a *single* sentence?
- Does the code compile?
- Do the tests pass?

Answer (score 1):

The main source of loss for beginners I think would be failing to properly add and commit content. So you should teach them how to check that their work has been committed. For example explain the `git commit` message:

> nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

And show them how to use the `git status` command and read its output, and emphasize that they should verify that there are no unsaved changes after a commit.

The other potential source of data loss is mistakes when trying to do fancy things. Likely mistakes are small typos, forgetting flags, and performing steps of a multi-step task out of order. So if you were teaching a programming course and only needed to teach the bare minimum of version control then I would say to teach only tasks involving a minimum of steps, and a minimum of flags:

A basic solo workflow that uses only `commit` to save work, and `revert` in order to roll back offers virtually no room for data-losing mistakes. A solo user can probably get away with using nothing but the following commands but still get a fair bit of value out of source control.

```
git commit -a
git revert
git status
git diff
git log
```

However, as the module is about version control you probably need to cover more than just the bare minimum to get by. In that case, when you cover advanced tasks you should discuss likely pitfalls in each command (i.e., point out specific opportunities where the likely mistakes I talked about above cause data loss), discuss specific warning and error messages. Also include plenty of exercises that deliberately destroy data, so that students see what that's like.

You may also want to cover git internals so that the students have a proper mental model of how data is stored in git repos and show some advanced cases of data recovery ([for example](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/236238)).

---

Pointing out that version control is not a backup (and backups are not version control) seems reasonable.

I wouldn't say avoiding `git rebase` or history rewriting is a good rule in general since those can be very useful features of a source control system, and it seems reasonable to teach them in a course on source control.

Answer (score 1):

The one thing users should be aware of is that Git is not meant as another replacement for backups. Quite the contrary: Git is built to forget information.

For example, you cannot commit any hook scripts in the repository. Hooks are intentionally local to every instance of a repository. The same applies to "rerere" conflict resolution.

Also, the history of branches (like when was that commit in which branch) is not recorded. Branches only exist as a pointer without history.

And last but not least, you can never really be sure that a commit you made is actually preserved in some other repository. It's very easy to forget about whether a commit actually is distributed to other repositories, which might destroy work if you delete your single repository that hosts a change.

One final way to get rid of necessary work in progress is: stash uncommitted and unregistered files (which will not stash them), and then reset --hard (which will delete these files without a trace). My coworker still gets mad when remembering this fail...

Comment: You *can* commit hook scripts, sort of: write the hook script, add and commit, and make the `.git/hooks/whatever` a link—hard or symbolic—back to the script.  It's a bit error-prone though, e.g., hard links get broken, people forget to make the link in the `.git` dir, etc.

Comment: @torek: You can commit the hook's code. You can commit the way to link the hook. But you cannot enforce the hooks, and they are not automatically committed and put in place. Git simply does not offer to treat them as part of the repository. If the user however want's it, they must do it on their own.

Comment: Yes, that's (part of) what I mean about error-prone.  It's still reasonable to commit the hook, etc, to make it easy for the repo-user; you just can't *enforce* it.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you mean by "beginner-level programmers," it could be good to tell them to look at some different user interfaces for git when they start out. Github for windows and Github for mac are good examples. They can be found at http://windows.github.com/ and http://mac.github.com/ respectively. Those user interfaces show which files have not been tracked and allow you to commit them very easily. I wouldn't call them a full replacement for the command line, but it could be a good way to start teaching them how things like commits and branching work. There isn't currently a Linux interface from GitHub, but there are other interfaces at http://git-scm.com/downloads/guis . As they become familiar with the ideas of commits and branches they can then transition to the command line to access more of Git's features.